# как правильно задать заголовок

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, flask, header

делал два варианта оба записывают в header но почему то не могу достучится из javascript'а

и так вариант **1**

```
@app.route('/getAllJobs', methods=['GET', 'OPTIONS'])
@crossdomain(origin='*')
def allJobs():
with open(current_app.static_folder + "/jobs.json", "r", encoding="utf-8") as read_file:
    data = json.load(read_file)

resp = make_response(jsonify(data))
resp.headers['total-jobs'] = 15

return resp
```

вариант **2** через

```
@app.after_request
def apply_caching(response):
   response.headers["total-jobs"] = 15
   return response
```

в обоих случаях получаю вот такую картину и вроде все нормально
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но в javascript'е его нет точнее немогу достучится...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

вопрос решен!
дело в том что надо было явно разрешить на `Access-Control-Expose-Headers`

```
resp.headers['Access-Control-Expose-Headers'] = 'total-jobs'
```